# Efficient substring parsing of large fixed length text file in Bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a large text file (millions of records) of fixed length data and need to extract **unique** substrings and create a number of arrays with those values. I have a working version, however I'm wondering if performance can be improved since I need to run the script iteratively.

$_file5 looks like:

```
138000010065011417865201710152017102122
138000010067710416865201710152017102133
138000010131490417865201710152017102124
138000010142349413865201710152017102154
138400010142356417865201710152017102165
130000101694334417865201710152017102176
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do

    _in=0
    _set=${line:15:6}
    _startDate=${line:21:8}
    _id="$_account-$_set-$_startDate"

    for element in "${_subsets[@]}"; do
        if [[ $element == "$_set" ]]; then
            _in=1
            break
        fi
    done

    # If we find a new one and it's not 504721
    if [ $_in -eq 0 ] && [ $_set != "504721" ] ; then
        _subsets=("${_subsets[@]}" "$_set")
        _ids=("${_ids[@]}" "$_id")
    fi

done < $_file5
```

And this yields:

```
_subsets=("417865","416865","413865")

_ids=("9899-417865-20171015", "9899-416865-20171015", "9899-413865-20171015")
```

I'm not sure if sed or awk would be better here and can't find a way to implement either. Thanks.

---

**EDIT: Benchmark Tests**

So I benchmarked my original solution against the two provided. Ran this over 10 times and all results where similar to below.

```
# Bash read
real    0m8.423s
user    0m8.115s
sys     0m0.307s

# Using sort -u (@randomir)
real    0m0.719s
user    0m0.693s
sys     0m0.041s

# Using awk (@shellter)
real    0m0.159s
user    0m0.152s
sys     0m0.007s
```

Looks like awk wins this one. Regardless, the performance improvement from my original code is substantial. Thank you both for your contributions.

Comment: Please show us sample Input_file and sample expected output in code tags too.

Comment: Added input and output expectations

Comment: I don't think you can process that much amount of data using any tools in significantly less time..

Comment: `if [ $_in -eq 0 ] && [ $_set != "504721" ]` might be better written as `if (( $_in == 0 )) && (( $_set != 504721 )) ` since `[` is a builtin.  It is possible that  this could perform better but I doubt it would be measurable, worth a try though.  Appending onto an array can be done with `+=`, for example `_subsets+=("$_set")` (introduced at Bash 3.1).  Again, performance improvement would only be significant with very large arrays.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, have you run the sort/grep twice (for both arrays), or only once? (If twice, that can be optimized; I wasn't sure what exactly you need) Also, can you try swapping grep and sort (in case there are a lot of records you want to skip)? Btw, what's the number of lines in the initial file, and what's the expected array length in the end?

Comment: I tried swapping sort and grep but it doesn't make a difference. The arrays always have less than 40 elements. And yes, sort was run twice so your solution may be faster if we alter it to issue a single sort and grep. But, mathematically, even if we cut that time in half, the awk still seems more efficient. Will need to test.

Comment: Well, if you have a huge input file, but only ~40 elements in output, then it makes sense for `awk` to be faster -- `sort` needs to sort a huge file (`O(N*logN)`), then filter the dupes (`O(N)`), for a large `N`. OTOH, `awk` needs to pass through the large input only once, checking for dupes along the way via set membership testing. Since the set of uniques is small, membership testing only `O(1)`, making the overall time `O(N)`. In case there are less dupes, `awk` would have `O(N*log(N))` amortized, and `O(N^2)` in worst case. Not to mention the higher constant per-instruction overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an `awk` solution embedded in a `bash` script:

```
#!/bin/bash
fn_parser() {
  awk '
    BEGIN{ _account="9899" }
    { _set=substr($0,16,6)
      _startDate=substr($0,22,8)
      #dbg print "#dbg:_set=" _set "\t_startDate=" _startDate
      if (_set != "504721") {
        _id= _account "-" _set"-" _startDate
        ids[_id] = _id
        sets[_set]=_set
      }
    }
    END {
      printf "_subsets=("
      for (s in sets) { printf("%s\"%s\"" , (commaCtr++ ? "," : ""), sets[s]) }
      print ");"
      printf "_ids=("
      for (i in ids) { printf("%s\"%s\"" , (commaCtr2++ ? "," : ""), ids[i]) }
      print ")"
    }
  ' "${@}"
}

#dbg set -vx
eval $( echo $(fn_parser *.txt) )
echo "_subsets="$_subsets
echo "_ids="$_ids
```

**output**

```
_subsets=413865,417865,416865
_ids=9899-416865-20171015,9899-413865-20171015,9899-417865-20171015
```

Which I believe would be the same output your script would get if you did an `echo` on your variable names.

I didn't see that `_account` was being extracted from your file, and assume it is passed in from a previous step in your batch. But until I know if that is a critical piece, I'll have to come back to figuring out how to pass in var to a function that calls `awk`.

People won't like using eval, but hopefully no one will embed `/bin/rm -rf /` into your data set ;-)

I use the `eval` so that the data extracted is available via the shell variables. You  can uncomment the `#dbg` before the `eval` line to see how the code is executing in the "layers" of `function`, `eval`, var=value assignments.

Hopefully, you see how the `awk` script is a transcription of your code into `awk`.

It does rely on the fact that arrays can contain only 1 copy of a key/value pair.

I'd really appreciate if you post timings for all solutions submitted. (You could reduce the file size by 1/2 and still have a good test). Be sure to run each version several times, and discard the first run.

IHTH

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can beat the performance of `sort -u` with `bash` loops (except in **corner cases**, as [this one turned out to be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47121868/efficient-substring-parsing-of-large-fixed-length-text-file-in-bash/?noredirect=1#comment81199029_47121868), see footnote<sup>✻</sup>).

To reduce the list of strings you have in `file` to a list of unique strings (set), based on a substring:

```
sort -k1.16,1.21 -u file >set
```

Then, to filter-out the unwanted id, `504721`, starting at position `16`, you can use `grep -v`:

```
grep -vE '.{15}504721' set
```

Finally, reformat the remaining lines and store them in arrays with `cut`/`sed`/`awk`/`bash`.

So, to populate the **`_subsets` array**, for example:

```
$ _subsets=($(sort -k1.16,1.21 -u file | grep -vE '.{15}504721' | cut -c16-21))
$ printf "%s\n" "${_subsets[@]}"
413865
416865
417865
```

or, to populate the **`_ids` array**:

```
$ _ids=($(sort -k1.16,1.21 -u file | grep -vE '.{15}504721' | sed -E 's/^.{15}(.{6})(.{8}).*/9899-\1-\2/'))
$ printf "%s\n" "${_ids[@]}"
9899-413865-20171015
9899-416865-20171015
9899-417865-20171015
```

---

<sup>✻</sup> If the input file is huge, but it contains only a **small number (`~40`) of unique elements** (for the relevant field), then it makes perfect sense for the [`awk` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47123791/404556) to be faster. `sort` needs to sort a huge file (`O(N*logN)`), then filter the dupes (`O(N)`), all for a large N. On the other hand, `awk` needs to pass through the large input only once, **checking for dupes along the way via set membership testing**. Since the set of uniques is small, membership testing takes only `O(1)` (on average, but for such a small set, practically constant even in worst case), making the overall time `O(N)`.

In case there were less dupes, `awk` would have `O(N*log(N))` amortized, and `O(N2)` worst case. Not to mention the higher constant per-instruction overhead.

**In short**: you have to know **how your data looks like before choosing the right tool for the job**.

Comment: start with the `grep -v`, and the expensive `sort` kas to sort less.